# Why can't I perform supervised classification using Landsat 8 SR images in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, landsat-8

This is the link to the code.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/ba342d996547c4fa8151bc99052036cf

This error message appears

[image: This error message appears]

```
var ColecaoL8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');
var diltroDataL8 = ColecaoL8.filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31');
var ComposicaoL8= ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
collection: diltroDataL8, asFloat: true});
Map.addLayer(ComposicaoL8 , {'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max:0.3}, 'Composição Imagens Landsat 8');

var classes = urban.merge(vegetation).merge(water);

var bandas = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];

var treinamento = ComposicaoL8.select(bandas).sampleRegions({
  collection: classes, 
  properties: ['landcover'], 
  scale: 30});

var classificar = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
  features: treinamento, 
  classProperty: 'landcover', 
  inputProperties: bandas});
//print(classificar.explain());

var classificado = ComposicaoL8.select(bandas).classify(classificar);
Map.addLayer(classificado, {min: 0, max: 2, palette: ['red', 'green', 'blue']},'Classificação');

//////////////////// VEGETAÇÃO ////////////////////
var vegetacao = classificado.select('classification').eq(1);//vegetação tem valor 1
//Map.addLayer(vegetacao);

var areaVegetacao = vegetacao.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1e6);

var statVegetacao = areaVegetacao.reduceRegion ({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9});
print ('Área de Vegetação (km²)', statVegetacao);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Please add more context to your question, details and the complete code, if the link becomes invalid, the code will stay here and help, maybe, other people.

Comment: I hope I have satisfied your request

Answer (score 3):

The function **ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite** works on raw scenes but from what I can see you are using Landsat 8 Surface reflectance dataset. You might want to try this one instead

```
var ColecaoL8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1');
```

Comment: That works in raw scenes I know. But isn't there any way to use it on surface scenes?

Comment: Well you can't use the **simpleComposite** function on surface reflectance and even if we manage that it wouldn't make much sense as the function "selects a subset of scenes at each location, converts to TOA reflectance, applies the simple cloud score and takes the median of the least cloudy pixels" as mentioned  here - https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/landsat. What you can do is, since its already surface reflectance, remove the cloudy pixels and do a median by using **median** function in your image collection. Ultimately what you are looking for is a composite image for 2016.